# I have to attend to a party tomorrow, but I forgot what it was

Tags: visual, word-problem

Today, my phone notified me of something that seemed important.

> tomorrow -> party with friends

I completely forgot what it was for. I proceeded to ask my friends about a party of some kind that will happen tomorrow, but they barely helped me.

Here is what I gathered from them :

Start from your house facing south, then : turn, go straight ahead once, turn, straight ahead twice.
Or is it this particular order ? Man, I don't know anymore... All I know for sure is that going straight ahead thrice won't make it at all.

Here is a rough representation on where I live, and where all my friends are :

```
+--L--+--E--+--A--+--N--+--V--+--T--+--S--+
|     |     |     |     |     |     |     |
S     Z     A     P     M     J     P     T
|     |     |     |     |     |     |     |
+--A--+--C--+--P--+--M--+--A--+--N--+--E--+
|     |     |     |     |     |     |     |
I     V     N     D     S     M     T     K
|     |     |     |     |     |     |     |
+--A--+--N--+--I--+--E--+--E--+--S--+--R--+
|     |     |     |     |     |     |     |
R     A     A     M     L     E     B     M
|     |     |     |     |     |     |     |
+--M--+--D--+--#--+--B--+--X--+--H--+--O--+    # : My house
|     |     |     |     |     |     |     |    
O     B     F     K     N     B     W     O
|     |     |     |     |     |     |     |
+--M--+--L--+--F--+--A--+--S--+--O--+--A--+
|     |     |     |     |     |     |     |
S     O     N     E     M     O     Z     R
|     |     |     |     |     |     |     |
+--F--+--C--+--G--+--W--+--U--+--N--+--E--+
|     |     |     |     |     |     |     |
B     M     <     N     L     X     C     O
|     |     |     |     |     |     |     |
+--W--+--F--+--G--+--U--+--I--+--U--+--Y--+
```

This is how travelling goes (example for 1 action)

```
+-----+-----+
|     |     |
|     B     |  B : Straight ahead twice
|     |     |
+-----+-----+
|     |     |
|     A     |  A : Straight ahead once
|     |     |
+--L--+--R--+  L : turn left, R : turn right
|     ^     |  ^ : current direction
|     $     |  $ : current position
|     |     |
+-----+-----+
```

Also, turning by 180° is not a reasonable option. Only these 4 listed above are allowed.
If I happen to go off the map, I must have done it wrong somewhere.

Can you help me finding out **what will happen tomorrow**, and **where will it happen** ?

---

After scratching my head for a while, another friend came to my house briefly.
He told me that the map I drew was, I quote, "sucky and bland".
Then he gave me this :

[image: better image, because visual tag, right ? (added color blindness thing)]

"What's with all these colors ? I don't get it !" I said.

"Just a little push of help, you can do without them.", he replied.
Then he told me a hint about this new map.

> "At the end of a chosen path, you can arrive a certain number of times at the side of a colored square. If you don't, you're just off track."

Then he left promptly.

"Well, thanks ... I guess"

---

I received *yet another* SMS, telling me this :

> The event will turn 13 tomorrow, hope you brought a suitable gift for her.
> As for the who and the what, use all the letters you found.

Comment: What is the "<" in the second last line of the grid? It looks like that might be the answer

Comment: Something is definitely special with this friend. Perhaps he's pointing to a certain direction.

Comment: If we start at the S in the top right.  Travelling towards the right to the T is a right, correct?  Continuing to travel to K, M, O is three straights, correct?

Comment: I'll post some examples to clarify the travelling.

Comment: The second map is not great for colour blind folk like me, I cant really tell which squares are the same colour. How many colours are there? Also, does "the side of a colored square" mean the same side of the same square, a side of the same square, some sides of some squares of the same colour, or...?

Comment: I didn't take color blindness into account, my bad. Gotta edit that as soon as possible. Also, there is a letter on each side of each square, if both squares around a letter are not colored, it means that the path was wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are going to

> Hannah's anniversary

Because

> The  "<    N" indicates the North (left side), so facing South is facing the right side of the map.
>
>   There are 4 moves : turn, ahead, turn, ahead*2 but we don't know the order except that it can not be ahead*3 so we can have :
>  - turn -> ahead -> turn -> ahead ahead
>  - turn -> ahead ahead -> turn -> ahead
>  - ahead -> turn -> ahead ahead -> turn
>  - ahead ahead -> turn -> ahead -> turn
>  - ahead -> turn -> turn -> ahead ahead
>  - ahead ahead -> turn -> turn -> ahead
>
>   Here are all the possible ending points if we take every possbile way:
>
>  [image]
>
>  Letters are : ENVAANNERLAAFUNFUI
>
>  ROT13 give the letters RAINNAAREYNNSHASHV
>  which is an anagram of HANNAH'S ANNIVERSARY

Comment: The colors were here to help you to not find incorrect paths, now they are of no use at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Tomorrow

> You have a party with your friends at the place "M" next to the "<", in M's backyard.

Reason

> Your phone reminded you of a party with your friends. And your direction clue takes us to the spot "<". Taking the hint provided, the "<" points to M. "<" also looks like a "back" symbol. So going with that, the party is in M's backyard.

Comment: Not the right answer. By the way, How can I go south from my house ?

Comment: You either go left or right and then head south.

Comment: @Anton could you provide a compass for the map? Or would that give the answer away?

Comment: There is a compass on the map. I don't see where the problem is. :)

Comment: < must be south then

Answer (score 0):

Tomorrow you will have a party in...

> your own house

From the current direction

> "<" you are facing that way. Let's call it West

Start from your house by going south

> you will go backwards facing West and that will land on "B"

then turn

> It means turn 180 degress to face East.

go straight ahead once

> Go straight once facing East and that will land on "X"

turn

> turn again 180 degress facing West

straight ahead twice

> go straight two times and that will land back to your house B-> #

Comment: will update my answer, OP edited the question lol

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell we do not know which way is south (although you do).

However, if

- "Start from your house by going south" is not part of the "particular order" of which you are unsure;
- "All I know for sure is that going straight ahead thrice won't make it at all" applies at each stage where you are to go straight ahead once *or* twice; and
- The directions, when in their correct order, lead to a unique location (or at least a unique friend)

Then

> South must be left on your diagram (so straight ahead thrice at the start would take us off map).
>  Our first turn must be right (so that then going straight ahead thrice will again take us off map).
>  Now the only unique friend label we may reach is to "Start from your house by going south (left), then, straight ahead twice, turn (right), go straight ahead once, turn (right)" leading to A's residence nearest the south-west (nearest the top-left of your diagram):
>
> ```
> +-----+-----+---
> |     |     |
> |     |     |
> |     |     |
> +--A--+-----+
> |     |     |
> I     |     |
> |     |     |
> +-----+-----+
> |     |     |
> R     |     |
> |     |     |
> +--M--+-----+-<#
> ```

Comment: There is a problem when starting to the left : with a valid combination like Ahead once, turn Left, turn Right, Ahead twice, we go off the map.

Comment: Isn't this the only valid, unique route with south as left? That was my logic.

Comment: I believe the problem is a little more complex than having one single unique path, if you know what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

Could it mean that you will attend to ...

> a Super Smash Brothers Melee tournament ?

Let's take a look at the map again, shall we ?

> `+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
>     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |
>     |     |     |     P     |     |     |     |
>     |     |     |   / | \   |     |     |     |
>     +-----+-----+--P--+--M--+-----+-----+-----+
>     |     |     |   \ | /   |     |     |     |
>     |     |     |     D     |     M  -  T  -  K
>     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |
>     +--A--+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
>     |/    |     |     |     |     |     |     |
>     R     A     A     |     |     |     B  -  M
>     |\  / | \ / |     |     |     |     | \ / |
>     +--M--+--D--+--#--+-----+--X--+--H--+--O--+    # : My house
>     |     |     |           |   \ | /   | / \ | 
>     O  -  B     |     K     N  ?  B     W     O
>     |   / |     |         / |     | \   |     |
>     +--M--+--L--+--F--|--A--+--S--+--O--+-----+
>     |   \ |   \ | /       \ |     |     |     |
>     |     O     N     E     M     |     |     |
>     |     | \   |           |     |     |     |
>     +-----+--C--+--G--|-----+-----+-----+-----+
>     |     |     |           |     |     |     |
>     |     M     <     N     |     |     |     |
>     |     |     |           |     |     |     |
>     +-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+`

That's right, these guys are invited to the party :

> - MTK : MewTwoKing
>  - PPMD
>  - ARMADA
>  - HBOX : HungryBox
>  - LFN : Leffen
>  - KEN

And you're going to

> get completely wrecked (by receiving a Wombo Combo, probably).
>  ...
>  aside from that, you're going to **M**ango's house (the M pointed by the **<**) , who might be upset to have his name changed to "Mambo" on the map by the letters of hbox.

As for the dates :

> Current year is <s>20XX, everybody plays Fox</s>
> Current date is December 1st, 2014.
> it is exactly 1 day before the 13th anniversary  of the release of [Super Smash Bros Melee](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_Smash_Bros._Melee) in north america.
> Make sure to gift your girlfriend a gamecube controller, everyone has the right to have fun.

Concerning the colors ...

> We can use the grayest vertical & horizontal lines to form the Super Smash Bros logo.

Comment: How the hell were we supposed to get that? This is literally impossible if you don't know Super Smash Bros players, even moreso if you don't know the way you abbreviated them. Where did the lines come from? What happened to the directions?